# jQuery get element by name[#] array

Tags: jquery

I have a select dropdown that has a name attribute[12], how can I use jquery to get that element by its name only?

```
<select name="attribute[12]"></select>
```

Currently I am trying to access it by using:

```
$('select[name="attribute[12]"]')
```

Comment: It should work. What is the issue? http://jsfiddle.net/Fnqv8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('select[name="attribute\\[12\\]"]')
```

Your `select` tag's name is containing two `meta-characters`  `[` and `]`. You have to escape it in order to make your selector working. Please read [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for full reference.

Comment: @j08691 weird, maybe the version of jquery i'm using is older, but that shouldn't be the case

Comment: @j08691 As far I have learnt, Escaping the meta-characters are the good practice and the right method. But I am curious to know how is that working.? any ideas.?